# Allow only one action use non secured connection at ASP.NET mvc 4, c#

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, https

At my web application I need to create an action what will be accessible using http non secured connection. All other have to be accessible for https only.
I found that I can use `[RequireHttps]` attribute for controller and action.

*But is there something like `[AllowHttp]` attribute?*

I do not want to put to all controller's action `[RequireHttps]` attribute. It's easier to put `[RequireHttps]` to Controller and `[AllowHttp]` to one action what can be accessed unsecured. Of course if this attribute is available

I mean something like we can do with Authentication. `[Authorize]` to controller and `[AllowAnonymous]` for some actions what can be accessed without authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the source of AuthorizeAttribute it checks the presence of AllowAnonymousAttribute

```
 bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                                 || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);
```

So you can dervive your own attribute from RequireHttps and add the same check so it will look like

```
 if (!skipAuthorization && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {

            HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
```

and istead of AllowAnonymousAttribute you can add your own AllowHttpAttribute and mark your action with this new AllowHttpAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lanrik, i finished with this code:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
//
// Summary:
// Represents an attribute that forces an unsecured HTTP request to be re-sent over
//     HTTPS.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomRequireHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Permanent { get; private set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute class.
    public CustomRequireHttpsAttribute()
        : this(permanent: false)
    {

    }

    public CustomRequireHttpsAttribute(bool permanent)
    {
        Permanent = permanent;
    }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether a request is secured (HTTPS) and, if it is not, calls the
    //     System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute.HandleNonHttpsRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext)
    //     method.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   filterContext:
    //     An object that encapsulates information that is required in order to use the
    //     System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute attribute.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The filterContext parameter is null.
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowHttpAttribute), inherit: true)
                             || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowHttpAttribute), inherit: true);
        if (!skipAuthorization && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Handles unsecured HTTP requests that are sent to the action method.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   filterContext:
    //     An object that encapsulates information that is required in order to use the
    //     System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute attribute.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The HTTP request contains an invalid transfer method override. All GET requests
    //     are considered invalid.
    protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("CustomRequireHttpsAttribute_MustUseSsl");
        }

        string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url, Permanent);
    }
}
//
// Summary:
//     Represents an attribute that marks controllers and actions to skip the System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute
//     during authorization.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class AllowHttpAttribute : Attribute
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Mvc.AllowHttpAttribute class.
    public AllowHttpAttribute()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

There isn't any innovation here, only copying and arrangement.
Again, thanks to @lavrik for the excellent reference and idea.